# Displaying .0 after round numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rounding

I’ve made a calculator using Doubles in Swift. The problem is that when I display the outcome it will display .0 at the end even if it’s a round number. I have tried the round() function but since it’s a double it still seems to always display .0 . In Objective-c i did this by typing:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@”%.0f”, RunningTotal]; //RunningTotal being the outcome
```

In this case there would be no decimals at all which there would if there stood @”%.3f” for example.

Does anyone know how to do this in swift? I’ve looked around on different forums but couldn’t find it anywhere... Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your can do the same in Swift.

```
let runningTotal = 12.0
let string = String(format:"%.0f", runningTotal)
println(string) // Output: 12
```

Generally, this would round the floating point number to the next integer.

The `%g` format could also be used, because that does not print trailing
zeros after the decimal point, for example:

```
String(format:"%g", 12.0) // 12
String(format:"%g", 12.3) // 12.3
```

For more advanced conversions, have a look at `NSNumberFormatter`.